# MongoDB won't keep running in a Docker container

Tags: configuration, docker, mongodb

I want to set up a MongoDB Docker container which would work based on a configuration file I specify. Here it is:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /data/db/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,162.243.243.233
```

I downloaded the Dockerfile and docker-entrypoint.sh from Docker's GitHub and modified the first one so that it meets my needs. Here's the relevant part of what I've got:

```
ENV MONGO_MAJOR 3.2
ENV MONGO_VERSION 3.2.6
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/$MONGO_MAJOR main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org.list
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
            mongodb-org=$MONGO_VERSION \
            mongodb-org-server=$MONGO_VERSION \
            mongodb-org-shell=$MONGO_VERSION \
            mongodb-org-mongos=$MONGO_VERSION \
            mongodb-org-tools=$MONGO_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb \
    && mv /etc/mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf.orig
RUN mkdir -p /data /data/db /data/configdb \
    && chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data /data/db /data/configdb
VOLUME /data /data/db /data/configdb /etc
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Add the custom config file
ADD ["mongod.conf","/data"]

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["mongod", "--config", "/data/mongod.conf"]
```

When I try to build the image, it succeeds. After `docker run` it exits as soon as gets created.

When the last line in the Dockerfile looks like `CMD ["mongod"]`, everything's fine, the container's up and running, but accessible only from localhost. According to my `mongod.conf`, I'm trying to extend the access to my IP address.

The config looks fine and YAML valid. It is also accessible to the container (`docker start -ai <CID>` gives no `entrypoint.sh` issue). What's the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you run the logs and add the output to your question?

Comment: If you mean `docker logs <CID>`, that gives no output. The container is exited of.

Comment: Try `docker exec -ti <CID> bash`. It will bypass the entrypoint and gives you a shell. Then run your entrypoint script manually and see what happens.

Comment: It tells me the container ain't running. When I try to start it, it exits straightaway.

Comment: Try `docker run -ti <IMAGE> bash`. Then MongoDB daemon manually. Do not use the entrypoint.

Comment: Started the daemon with the config manually. My Mac still can't connect to the container (error 61: connection refused). The firewall is open on port 27017 from 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: When running `mongod` manually, add verbose argument to have more details. `mongod --config /data/mongod.conf --verbose`.

Comment: But an early guess would be your config file has an error.

Comment: I will try with another one tomorrow, from the server where Mongo runs without Docker.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the config file or the container. When running mongod with a custom config file, it is considered as a child process. As soon as the child process started, the parent (i.e, mongod exits) which causes the container to exit. I am facing the same issue. **"about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 48
child process started successfully, parent exiting"** This is what i get when executing the command manually inside the container.